# Observe database functions not working after updating to xcode 10.2.1

Tags: xcode, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

My iOS app was working until I updated to latest Xcode (10.2.1) and updated pods with "pod update". I was previously using Xcode 9.4.1 and swift 3. I did the update because I couldn´t upload to appstore with that version of Xcode.

The rest of the functions work fine (including firebase phone authentication) but all the "Observe" firebase database functions are never triggered. It builds succesfully and no errors shown.

I tried with no success:

-Download plist file from firebase.

-Set database rules to true for read and write.

-Set Deployment Target to 11.0 and podFile platform: ios, '11.0'

podFile:

```
platform :ios, '12.0'

target 'appname' do
 use_frameworks!
pod 'Firebase/Database'
pod 'Firebase/Auth'
pod 'Firebase/Storage'
pod 'SwiftyStoreKit'
pod 'Onboard'
pod 'SDWebImage'
pod 'IQKeyboardManagerSwift'
end
```

Firebase initialized in AppDelegate - didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:

```
FirebaseApp.configure()
```

Everything works as expected until this:

```
Auth.auth().signIn(with: credential) { (user,error) in
    if error != nil {
        print(error)
    } else {
        print(phone number: \(String(describing: user?.user.phoneNumber))")//this is successfully printed
        let userInfo = user?.user.providerData[0]
        print(Provider ID: \(String(describing: userInfo?.providerID))")//this is successfully printed

        if let user = Auth.auth().currentUser {
            let uid = user.uid
            let ref = Database.database().reference()
            ref.child("users").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
                if snapshot.hasChild(uid) {
                    print("user already exists")//this never gets printed
                } else {
                    let values: [String: AnyObject] = ["phoneNumber": user.phoneNumber as AnyObject]
                    let userRef = ref.child("users").child(uid)
                    userRef.updateChildValues(values, withCompletionBlock: { (err,ref) in//user never gets created in database but it is created in firebase
                        if err != nil {
                            print(err)
                            return
                        }
                    })
                }
                let tabBarController = CustomTabBarController()//this never gets executed
                present(tabBarController, animated: true)
            })
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It's going to be really tough to answer this question as the issue could be a number of things; anywhere from how the app and Firebase is set up to authentication issues to rules. It could even be an internet issue. I am running XCode 10.2.1, Firebase 6.0.0 and my app just built and ran successfully. Can we take a look at your podFile, and how you are initializing Firebase?

Comment: I edited the answer, Is that the correct info? I think it´s not an internet problem, when I load the old version of the app it works, same with another app connected to the same firebase project. I´m testing on iPhone 6 (iOS 12.3).

Comment: The podfile and initialization all look correct. So you have two versions of the app, the old one which works and the new one which doesn't. Did you add your new app to the project in the Firebase console and download an updated plist for *that* app? Each separate app needs to have it's own plist.

Comment: I have 2 apps yes, 1 that was working before I updated and not working after the update, and another one that works before and after. Yes, they both have been added to the firebase project.

Comment: The app that still works I haven't updated the pods or anything as I don't need it on the appstore.

Comment: Any more ideas where I could be doing something wrong? Thanks Jay for your help.

Comment: I've created several Firebase apps with the same Firebase podfile(s) and they are working fine. The non-Firebase ones could have something to do with it or it could be something else entirely. I don't think it going to be possible to troubleshoot or provide an answer without more data points (Firebase init code, viewDidLoad or other init code) Perhaps you can comment out all of your code and strip it down to a base app. Then create a simple function to observe some node in firebase and see if it works. If it does, start uncommenting code until it fails.

Comment: Your code works for me - I copy and pasted it into a project and it's fine. But... There could be a few things preventing it from working. If this fails `let user = Auth.auth().currentUser` it won't do anything. I would add a breakpoint and step through the code to see if the user var gets populated. A second thing is that if you are not authenticated when you run this code, it will fail due to your Firebase Rules and by default will deny that read for unauth'd users. You may also have other Rules that are preventing the read so may want to include those in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the cocoapods version, I had 1.5.3. Once I updated to 1.7.2 everything works as expected.